# How can I clear the selected value of a Material-UI Autocomplete component after submitting a form?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using the React Hook Form library along with Material-UI components to validate a form. I want the Autocomplete Material-UI component to clear its selected value after the form is submitted. I have already implemented this functionality for the TextField, Select, and TinyMCE Editor components, but I am facing an issue with the Autocomplete component. Even after the form is submitted, the Autocomplete component retains the previously selected values. I have attempted several solutions, but none have been successful. Can you suggest any possible solutions?

[image]

***First Way***

> I used `reset({})` to reset the values after submitting the form, but as I mentioned, all the component values cleared except for the Autocomplete.

***Second Way***

> I used `setValue("tags",[])`, which I extracted from useForm, and added
> it to the onSubmit function, but it didn't have any effect.

***Third way***

> I used `const autocompleteRef = useRef(null)` but it didn't work.

```
type tagsData = {
  id: number | null;
  title: string;
};
const schema = yup.object({
  title: yup.string().required(),
  isPublished: yup.boolean().notRequired(),
  body: yup.string().notRequired(),
  image: yup.string().required(),
  userId: yup.string().required(),
  tags: yup.array().min(1, "انتخاب حداقل یک تگ اجباری است"),
  categoryId: yup.string().required(),
});


const AddEditPost = function ({
  typeOperation,
  onAdd,
  onEdit,
  editFormData,
}: any) {
  const initialState = {
    isPublished: editFormData?.isPublished || true,
    title: editFormData?.title || "",
    body: editFormData?.body || "",
    image: editFormData?.image || "",
    userId: editFormData?.userId || "da154cf1-aacb-46cf-a407-290c318244a7",
    tags: editFormData?.tags || [],
    categoryId: editFormData?.categoryId || "",
  };
  const [doFetchTags] = useThunk(fetchTags);
  const [doFetchCategories] = useThunk(fetchCategories);
  const { data: categoryData } = useAppSelector((state) => state.category);
  const { data: tagData } = useAppSelector((state) => state.tags);
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
    setValue,
  } = useForm<formPostValidationType>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: { ...initialState, tags: [] },
  });
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialState);
  const onSubmit = function (data: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", data.title);
    formData.append("body", data.body);
    formData.append("image", form.image); // append File object directly
    formData.append("userId", data.userId);

    formData.append("categoryId", data.categoryId);
    formData.append("isPublished", data.isPublished);
    formData.append("publishedAt", "");

    for (let i = 0; i < form.tags.length; i++) {
      formData.append("tags[]", form.tags[i]);
    }

    typeOperation === "Add" ? onAdd(formData) : onEdit(formData);
    reset({});
  };


  
  const handleAutocompleteChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<{}> | null,
    newValue: Array<any>
  ) => {
    const value = newValue.map((option) => option.id);
    setForm((prevForm) => ({ ...prevForm, tags: value }));
  };
  const onError = function (data: any) {
    console.log("errors:: ", data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    doFetchTags({ all: true });
    doFetchCategories({ all: true });
  }, [doFetchTags, doFetchCategories]);

  
  return (
    <>
      <Grid container sx={addEditFormStyle}>
        <form
          style={{ width: "100%", flexWrap: "wrap" }}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, (data) => onError(data))}
        >
      
          <Grid container mb={3} spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xl={6}>
              <Controller
                name="tags"
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <Autocomplete
                    id="tags"
                    multiple
                    options={tagData}
                    getOptionLabel={(option: any) => option?.title || ""}
                    fullWidth
                    sx={{ marginRight: "10px" }}
                    value={tagData.filter((option: tagsData) => {
                      return form.tags.includes(option.id);
                    })}
                    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                      const value = newValue.map(
                        (option: tagsData) => option.id
                      );
                      field.onChange(value);
                      handleAutocompleteChange(event, newValue);
                    }}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField
                        error={errors.tags ? true : false}
                        {...params}
                        label="تگ ها"
                        helperText={errors.tags && errors.tags.message}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </Grid>
        
          </Grid>
       
     
    
        </form>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why use the `Controller` wrapper if you're not passing on any props to `Autocomplete`? If you want to update the value it should be a controlled input (pass it a `value` prop).

Comment: @super,Thank you so much. Here's the corrected sentence: "Thank you so much. I went with "register" and also removed Controller,it solved my issue.